# sql bulk insert with generated key

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, insert, bulkinsert

I defined a table with an unique objected (generated)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(
    Id bigint   IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,Version    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    ,Date       DATE  NOT NULL
    ,Code       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Table1(Version,Date,Code) VALUES ('1.0','2018-04-16','8615');
INSERT INTO Table1(Version,Date,Code) VALUES ('1.0','2018-04-16','2285');
INSERT INTO Table1(Version,Date,Code) VALUES ('1.0','2018-04-16','11625');
```

Now I have a .csv. file with more information to insert. I suppose to use BULK INSERT like

```
BULK INSERT Table1 
FROM 'C:\test.csv' 
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
    ,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
```

the input file contains:

```
    1.0,2018-04-16,240061
    1.0,2018-04-17,3435
    1.0,2018-04-18,2143
    1.0,2018-04-19,44
    1.0,2018-04-20,2453
    1.0,2018-04-01,2012
    1.0,2018-04-22,123
    1.0,2018-04-23,9887
    1.0,2018-04-30,57
    1.0,2018-05-1,576
    1.0,2018-05-8,35
    1.0,2018-05-9,867
    1.0,2018-05-10,555
....
```

running the BULK INSERT statement results in errors

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 1 (Id).
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (Id).
```

What is the best way to insert a lot of data from the csv into de table? (more then 10000 rows)

Comment: You're right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

try specifying column name like

```
BULK INSERT Table1 (Version,Date,Code)
FROM 'C:\test.csv' 
WITH (
FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
,ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```